# CentOS: MS SQL driver installed and configured, yet not available to PHP

Tags: centos, php, sql-server

On a CentOS 7.3 machine running PHP 5.6 I have installed and configured the MS SQL driver for PDO, yet it is not available to PHP.

See that the driver is properly installed and configured:

```
$ yum list php56w-mssql
Installed Packages
php56w-mssql.x86_64            5.6.30-1.w7        @webtatic

$ cat /etc/php.d/mssql.ini
; Enable mssql extension module
extension=mssql.so
```

However, PHP doesn't recognize it:

```
$ php -i | grep 'PDO drivers'
PDO drivers => dblib, mysql, sqlite
```

**How might I troubleshoot this?**

Comment: You might start by ensuring that you don't have multiple php versions (one from the regular CentOS repo's and an extra from the webtatic repo) and that you're calling the correct binary

Comment: @HBruijn: In fact, I've only got PHP 5.6 from webtatic installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I was unable to get the MS SQL extension to work properly. However, **PHP can connect to MS SQL via [ODBC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft-open-database-connectivity-odbc)**:

```
$ yum list php56w-odbc
Installed Packages
php56w-odbc.x86_64    5.6.30-1.w7    @webtatic

$ cat /etc/php.d/odbc.ini 
extension=odbc.so
```

And then in PHP:

```
$mssqldriver = 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server';
$hostname='1.2.3.4';
$dbname='foobar';
$username='';
$password='';

$dsn = "odbc:Driver={$mssqldriver};Server={$hostname};Database={$dbname};MARS_Connection=yes";
$pdo= new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Be sure to specify [MARS Connection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets), otherwise the connection will be limited on only a single pending request.